# assign to a td table the value from a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a table in a loop in an asp page like this:

```
   foreach (ListItem item in check.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {

                    DropDownList drop = new DropDownList();

                    drop.Items.Add("1");
                    drop.Items.Add("2");

                    drop.DataValueField = "1";
                    drop.DataValueField = "2";





                    TableRow row = new TableRow();
                    TableCell celula = new TableCell();
                    celula.Style.Add("width", "200px");
                    celula.Style.Add("background-color", "red");

                    celula.RowSpan = 2;
                    celula.Text = item.Value;
                    TableCell celula1 = new TableCell();
                    celula1.Style.Add("background-color", "green");
                    celula1.Style.Add("width", "200px");

                    celula1.RowSpan = 2;

                    TableCell celula2 = new TableCell();
                    celula2.Style.Add("width", "200px");
                    celula2.Style.Add("background-color", "blue");
                    celula2.Text = "unu";
                    TableRow row1 = new TableRow();
                    TableCell cel = new TableCell();
                    cel.Text = "lalala";
                    cel.Style.Add("background-color", "brown");




                    celula1.Controls.Add(drop);
                    row.Cells.Add(celula);
                    row.Cells.Add(celula1);
                    row.Cells.Add(celula2);
                    row1.Cells.Add(cel);
                    this.tabel.Rows.Add(row);
                    this.tabel.Rows.Add(row1);



                }
            }
```

For each value I check, a new row is created with the value of the checked checkbox, a dropdownlist and 2 more cells. Now I want for each dropdownlist that I create to make something.So if I choose 1 for the first row something will appear and if I choose 1 for another row something else will appear. I made a selectedindexchanged but if I choose 1 from the first row it will show up for both rows. How can I refer separately for each dropdownlist that I create in the loop?? I'm using Asp.Net web application with c#

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as below.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    LoadData();
}
```

Define LoadData function as below

```
 private void LoadData()
 {
     foreach (ListItem item in check.Items)
     {
         if (item.Selected)
         {

             DropDownList drop = new DropDownList();

             drop.Items.Add("1");
             drop.Items.Add("2");

             drop.DataValueField = "1";
             drop.DataValueField = "2";
             drop.AutoPostBack = true;

             // assign id property to dropdown.

             drop.ID = "ddl_" + item.value.ToString();

             // add event handled for dynamically generated dropdown      
             drop.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddl_SelectedIndexChanged);



             TableRow row = new TableRow();
             TableCell celula = new TableCell();

             // assing ID property to cell.

             celula.ID = "celula_" + item.value.ToString();
             celula.Style.Add("width", "200px");
             celula.Style.Add("background-color", "red");

             celula.RowSpan = 2;
             celula.Text = "item " + item.Value.ToString();
             TableCell celula1 = new TableCell();
             celula1.Style.Add("background-color", "green");
             celula1.Style.Add("width", "200px");

             celula1.RowSpan = 2;

             TableCell celula2 = new TableCell();
             celula2.Style.Add("width", "200px");
             celula2.Style.Add("background-color", "blue");
             celula2.Text = "unu";
             TableRow row1 = new TableRow();
             TableCell cel = new TableCell();
             cel.Text = "lalala";
             cel.Style.Add("background-color", "brown");




             celula1.Controls.Add(drop);
             row.Cells.Add(celula);
             row.Cells.Add(celula1);
             row.Cells.Add(celula2);
             row1.Cells.Add(cel);
             this.tabel.Rows.Add(row);
             this.tabel.Rows.Add(row1);
         }
     }

    }
```

Handle event as below

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList dd = (DropDownList)sender;

    // you can get dropdown from table row over here.
    // process with it as per your requirement.

    string strdropdownID = ((System.Web.UI.Control)(dd)).ID;

    string id = strdropdownID.Split('_')[1].ToString();
    string tblcID = "celula_" + id.ToString();
    TableCell celula = (TableCell)tabel.FindControl(tblcID);
    celula.RowSpan = Convert.ToInt32(dd.SelectedValue);
}
```

Hope this will works for you...happy coding...

Comment: how can I use in the SelectedIndexChanged to assign to celula.RowSpan the value from the dropdownlist??

Comment: can u pls explain exact functionality on dropdown selected index changed event ?

Comment: so I have those drop down lists created on each row. For example I have 3 rows with 3 dropdownlists. If I select from the firs dropdownlist the value 1 then I want this value to assign it to the celula.RowSpan so it will be something like this:

Comment: var drop = (DropDownList)sender;
             if (drop.SelectedValue == "1")
             {
                 celula.RowSpan=drop.SelectedValue;
             }

Comment: for that you need assign ID property to celula. i have modified my answer.pls have a look ..that will surely helps you