# make dynamic table visible in all page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a dynamic table using c# and in one TableCell I have a dropdownlist.I've created an SelectedIndexChanged to my dropdownlist event and now I want to refer to my TableCell.

```
 public void CreareTabel()
{
TableRow row = new TableRow();
                    TableCell celula = new TableCell();
                    celula.Style.Add("width", "200px");
                    celula.Style.Add("background-color", "red");

                    celula.RowSpan = 2;}
```

and in my selectedindexchanged:

```
 private void drop_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             var drop = (DropDownList)sender;
             if (drop.SelectedValue == "1")
             {
                 celula.RowSpan= drop.SelectedValue;
             }

        }
```

But if I do it like this my celula.RowSpan isn't recognised. How can i refer to celula.Rowspan in my selectedindexchanged?????

Comment: I have given answer of same question in your older post . please click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072110/assign-to-a-td-table-the-value-from-a-dropdownlist/10072617#10072617)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
private void drop_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         var drop = (DropDownList)sender;
         TableCell celula = (TableCell)drop.Parent;
         if (drop.SelectedValue == "1")
         {
             celula.RowSpan= drop.SelectedValue;
         }

    }
```

What drop.Parent does is grab the parent of the dropdownlist, which is the tablecell that holds it.